# d3.js scales exact ticks count

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How do i retrive exact tick count from `d3.scale.linear()`?

As you can seed from [docs](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear_ticks):

> Returns **approximately** count representative values from the scale's input domain.

If i run code like this:

```
d3.scale.linear().domain([ymin - offset, ymax + offset]).range([100, 900]).ticks(6)
```

I may receive from 3 to 7 ticks regarding input domain.

So, what should i do if i need exact 6 evently spaced ticks from domain regarding they wouldn't be nice numbers such as multiples of powers of 10?

Comment: Use `.tickValues()` to set them explicitly.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I don't use SVG.axes, i just need to retrieve ticks from domain, is it possible?

Comment: You can't from the scales. However, you can simply divide the domain into the number of intervals you want.